# Function is changing wrong variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, reference

I have got a problem that changes wrong variable in a function(s) shown below.

```
def no_updown() -> int:
    print(g.matrix)
    count = 0
    arr = g.matrix
    arr = g.move_elements(arr)
    for x in range(g.size):
        for y in range(g.size - 1):
            if arr[y, x] == arr[y + 1, x] and arr[y, x] > 0:
                arr[y, x] *= 2
                arr[y + 1, x] = 0
                count += 1
    return count
```

And here is *g.move_elements*:

```
def move_elements(self, arr) -> np.matrix:
    for x in range(self.size):
        temp = 0
        for y in range(self.size):
            if not arr[y, x] == 0:
                arr[temp, x] = arr[y, x]
                if not temp == y:
                    arr[y, x] = 0
                temp += 1
    return arr
```

I want to operate only on *arr* from *no_updown()*. Instead what am I getting is *g.matrix* changed. I believe this has something to do with referencing, but I don't know quietly what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr = g.matrix
```

You have made `arr` and `g.matrix` refer to the same object. So naturally, changes made via either name are visible from the other.

I don't know what kind of object `g.matrix` is (although I can see it's not a Python list) but there's probably a way to copy it and avoid this problem. If it's a NumPy array, you can use [`numpy.copy`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html).

Comment: Right, didn't know that, such a basic... g.matrix is np.matrix, so I can use np.copy(). Thanks!